transitioning Azure Monitor log configuration file from using OpenCensus to OpenTelemetry
Good Morning,
I am working on transitioning our Azure Monitor log configuration file from using OpenCensus to OpenTelemetry.
This is because Azure Monitor support for OpencCensus will end on 30 September 2024, and recommend transitioning to OpenTelemetry as stated here.
I have looked through the documentation provided by Microsoft and need some additional support in order to complete this. Documentation here.
I am using the OpenCensus class AzureLogHandler and want to replicate this behavior in OpenTelemetry.
import logging
import os
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

class CustomDimensionsFilter(logging.Filter):
    """Add application-wide properties to AzureLogHandler records"""

    def __init__(self, custom_dimensions=None):
        self.custom_dimensions = custom_dimensions or {}

    def filter(self, record):
        """Adds the default custom_dimensions into the current log record"""
        cdim = self.custom_dimensions.copy()
        cdim.update(getattr(record, 'custom_dimensions', {}))
        record.custom_dimensions = cdim

        return True

SOURCEVERSION = os.getenv("BUILD_SOURCEVERSION")
BUILDNUMBER = os.getenv("BUILD_BUILDNUMBER")
logger_name = "Dealer_Portal"
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

default_properties = {
    'source_version': SOURCEVERSION,
    'build_number': BUILDNUMBER
}

azure_handler = AzureLogHandler()
azure_formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(user_uid)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
azure_handler.setFormatter(azure_formatter)
azure_handler.addFilter(CustomDimensionsFilter(default_properties))
azure_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(azure_handler)

Ideally I would like to find a simple solution for replacing AzureLogHandler() with an OpenTelemetry class. Any advice would be appreciated!

To transition from OpenCensus to OpenTelemetry while maintaining the functionality provided by AzureLogHandler, you'll want to use the OpenTelemetryLogExporter class. However, since OpenTelemetry has a slightly different architecture, the direct equivalent of AzureLogHandler doesn't exist in the traditional sense. Instead, you can use the OpenTelemetryPipelineBuilder class to construct a custom pipeline.
import logging
import os
from opentelemetry.sdk.logs import OpenTelemetryPipelineBuilder
from opentelemetry.exporter.azure.monitor import AzureMonitorExporter

class CustomDimensionsFilter(logging.Filter):
    """Add application-wide properties to AzureLogHandler records"""

    def __init__(self, custom_dimensions=None):
        self.custom_dimensions = custom_dimensions or {}

    def filter(self, record):
        """Adds the default custom_dimensions into the current log record"""
        cdim = self.custom_dimensions.copy()
        cdim.update(getattr(record, 'custom_dimensions', {}))
        record.custom_dimensions = cdim

        return True

SOURCEVERSION = os.getenv("BUILD_SOURCEVERSION")
BUILDNUMBER = os.getenv("BUILD_BUILDNUMBER")
logger_name = "Dealer_Portal"
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

default_properties = {
    'source_version': SOURCEVERSION,
    'build_number': BUILDNUMBER
}

# Set up OpenTelemetry with Azure Monitor Exporter
otel_exporter = AzureMonitorExporter()
otel_pipeline = OpenTelemetryPipelineBuilder().set_exporter(otel_exporter).build()

# Incorrectly assuming this pipeline can be added like a handler
otel_pipeline.addFilter(CustomDimensionsFilter(default_properties))
logger.addHandler(otel_pipeline)  # This line is intentionally wrong

# Set logging level and format
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

